# Activity Misbehaving when launched from BroadcastReceiver but works fine when Launched Manually

Tags: java, android, xml

The broadcast receiver reads SSID of the Wifi and if it is the desired SSID it launches the activity. When activity is launched(from broadcastreceiver), it does nothing.

The BroadcastReceiver:

```
    package com.example.mughal.tileviewtest.wifi;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.mughal.tileviewtest.LoadingActivity;
    import com.example.mughal.tileviewtest.Main2Activity;

    /**
     * Created by Mughal on 4/28/2016.
     */
    public class CheckWifi extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

            wifiInfo.getBSSID ();

            Intent i=new Intent(context, LoadingActivity.class);

            String temp=remove(wifiInfo.getSSID());


            String [] A=temp.split("_");
            if(A[0].equals("SPS"))
            {
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);

            }




        }
        String remove(String a)
        {
            String b;
            b=  a.substring(1, a.length()-1);
            return b;

        }


    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.mughal.tileviewtest">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
            <receiver android:name="com.example.mughal.tileviewtest.wifi.CheckWifi" >
                   
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                      
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
              </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".LoadingActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_loading"
                android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

loadingActivity:
        package com.example.mughal.tileviewtest;

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.text.format.Formatter;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.mughal.tileviewtest.databases.DBHelper;
    import com.example.mughal.tileviewtest.networking.AsyncGetMap;
    import com.example.mughal.tileviewtest.networking.TcpClient;
    import com.example.mughal.tileviewtest.networking.TcpHandler;
    import com.example.mughal.tileviewtest.objects.Floor;
    import com.example.mughal.tileviewtest.objects.Map;
    import com.example.mughal.tileviewtest.wifi.CheckWifi;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
     * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
     */
    public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TcpClient mTcpClient;
        String mapName;
        String ip;
        Context C;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
            C=getApplicationContext();
            /* get connected wifi*/



            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();


            String temp=wifiInfo.getSSID();
            temp=temp.substring(1,(temp.length()-1));
            String [] A=temp.split("_");
            if(A[0].equals("SPS"))
            {
            mapName=A[1];
            wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
            String tempIp = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wifiInfo.getIpAddress());
            String ipBreakDown[]=tempIp.split("\\.");
            ip=(ipBreakDown[0]+"."+ipBreakDown[1]+"."+ipBreakDown[2]+"."+"69");
                new ConnectTask().execute(mapName);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"NOT WITHIN SPS WIFI RANGE: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                this.finish();
            }
            /* if SPS_ , then ok; match name after _ */
        }


        private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TcpClient> {

            @Override
            protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... params) {
                //we create a TCPClient object and

                mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                    @Override
                    //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                    public void messageReceived(String message)
                    {
                        //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                        publishProgress(message);
                         Log.i("Debug", "Input message: " + message);
                    }
                },ip);
                mTcpClient.run(params[0]);
                return mTcpClient;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                Log.i("onProgressUpdate", values[0]);
                String path=values[0];
                mTcpClient.stopClient();
            /* check db for map with name */
                DBHelper dbh = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
                path=path.substring(0,path.length()-1);
                ArrayList<Map> maps = dbh.getMap(mapName);

            /* if present,get map from local db*/
                if(maps.isEmpty())
                {

                    new AsyncGetMap(getApplicationContext(),mapName,path,ip).execute();
                }
                else
                {
                    //get floors from db
                    ArrayList<Integer>floorNumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    ArrayList <Integer> TileNumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                    String [] pathSpl=path.split("-");
                    String [] pathSp2=pathSpl[0].split(",");
                    int psF=Integer.parseInt(pathSp2[0]);
                    int psT=Integer.parseInt(pathSp2[1]);
                    String [] fmark=pathSpl[1].split("@");

                    for(int i=0;i<fmark.length;i++){
                        String [] Tmark=fmark[i].split(":");
                        String [] Tmark2=Tmark[1].split(",");
                        int HeyHey = Integer.parseInt(Tmark[0]);
                        for(int j=0;j<Tmark2.length;j++){
                            floorNumbs.add(HeyHey);
                            TileNumbs.add(Integer.parseInt(Tmark2[j]));
                        }
                    }


                    int map_id = maps.get(0).getId();

                    ArrayList<Floor> floors = dbh.getFloors(map_id);

                    //marking the parking spot
                    floors.get((psF-1)).markPS(psT);


                   for(int i=0;i<floorNumbs.size();i++){
                       floors.get((floorNumbs.get(i)-1)).changeTileToMarked(TileNumbs.get(i));
                   }
                    ArrayList <Integer> hey= new ArrayList <Integer> ();

                    for(int l=0;l<floors.size();l++){
                        hey.add(floors.get(l).getRowSeparator());
                    }

                /* add floors as extra,start new activity */
                    Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    Bundle x = new Bundle();
                    x.putIntegerArrayList("RowSeps",hey);
                    x.putInt("current",1);
                    x.putInt("Total",floors.size());
                    for(int j=0;j<floors.size();j++)
                    {
                        int temp=j+1;
                        String K="floor"+Integer.toString(temp);
                        x.putIntegerArrayList(K, floors.get(j).getIntArraylist());

                    }

                    i.putExtra("MeraBundle",x);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does nothing"?

Comment: it doesnt execute this line:
    new ConnectTask().execute(mapName);

which is essential for my app to progress. They point of this activity is that it is simple an intermediate stage to start the main activity. It isnt launching that activity in case of being launched from the broadcastreceiver

Comment: You need to edit your question to provide more details. Is `(A[0].equals("SPS")` false? Are you getting the `Toast`? How do you know the `AsyncTask` isn't being executed? `TcpClient` looks looks it already runs asynchronously. Why do you have it in an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Assume '(A[0].equals("SPS")' returns true always. I tested by putting in Toasts in parts of the code. It excecutes till: 'new ConnectTask().execute(mapName);'. After this, the toasts stop(that is I put them inside the Asynctask but it wouldnt run). (Thank you for the Help btw)

Comment: You can't make `Toast`s directly from a non-UI thread, so if that's what you're using to determine if the `AsyncTask` is running, it's not going to work. Use log prints instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your context refers to the current activity running. Its working because LoadingActivity is an activity therefore it has a context that can be passed on, a reference to it. You are trying to start an Activity from a non-activity class, CheckWifi so your context in onReceive is just going to be null, it's not referencing an Activity.

if you had of googled the BroadcastReceiver documentation made available by Android you would of came across this:

"There is no way for a BroadcastReceiver to see or capture Intents used with startActivity(); likewise, when you broadcast an Intent, you will never find or start an Activity."

Comment: If the context passed on is null, why is the activity launching. This basically is what bamboozles me about all this.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can launch an activity from CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcastreceiver. This broadcast happens in the background. What you can do is create a notification from the receiver and launch your activity when user selects the notification.

Comment: But the Activity does Launch, but doesn't function ahead.